# How to make a link open multiple pages when clicked?

Tags: hyperref, urls, links

I have to create a hyperlink which opens two links with one click.

Is it possible using LaTeX?

I'm using `\href{<url>}{Open two links}`.

Comment: How is your reader set up to jump to multiple pages simultaneously?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

That would be a web question, not a `TeX` one, I guess. You can't really cause your reader to open multiple pages at once. I think even if you can do that it can be categorized as suspicious behavior by any anti-virus software. :)

You may want to try using `javascript` to do this. I really don't think, it will work, but that's the only way I can think of. The other option is to use a web side solution (for example a webpage and pop-ups).

Comment: Found this http://stackoverflow.com/questions/7064998/how-to-make-a-link-open-multiple-pages-when-clicked. I was just wondering if Latex have some feature for this. Anyway, thanks.

Comment: Yes, I was referring to this. You can use `javascript` in some `LaTeX` versions as well, but I don't think that the `windows.open` command works that way.

Answer (score 13):

The PDF format knows nested actions. `hyperref` supports this by option `nextacrtionraw` for `\href` in some rudimentary manner:

```
\documentclass{article}

\usepackage{hyperref}

\begin{document}
  \href[%
    nextactionraw={%
      <<%
        /Type/Action%
        /S/URI%
        /URI(http://meta.tex.stackexchange.com/)%
      >>%
    }%   
  ]{http://tex.stackexchange.com/}{Two links}

  \url{http://meta.tex.stackexchange.com/}
\end{document}
```

However, a PDF viewer is needed that supports that feature. And the action code is given in raw PDF syntax.